# Assign ASCII character to wire in Verilog

Tags: string, ascii, verilog, system-verilog

I understand that you can declare a string in a Verilog test bench as follows:

```
reg [8*14:1] string_value;  

initial 
    string_value = "Hello, World!";
```

I can then do things with this string, like use `$display` in a test bench to display it.

I haven't been successful in doing the same in a module when I flash it to my FPGA:

```
reg [8*14:1] string_value;  

always @(reset) 
begin
    string_value = "Hello, World!";
    // Do stuff with string value
```

Even assigning a single value does not work:

```
reg [8:1] char_value;  

always @(reset) 
begin
    char_value = "A";
    if (char_value == 8'h41)
        // Do stuff!
```

I want to shift the individual characters on an 8-bit bus to an LCD screen for display.

How can I work with strings in Verilog?

Comment: Are you trying to synthesize this?

Comment: @Adam12 - Yes, I'm trying to print text on an LCD screen connected to my FPGA development board. Since this wasn't clear to both you and toolic, I'll edit the question to be more specific: I want to assign these 8-bit character values to an output of my module through a shift register.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Do you get a synthesis error, or is the text simply not shown on the LCD?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

SystemVerilog should support string assignment as mentioned in spec:

```
For example, to store the 12-character string "Hello world\n" requires a variable 8x12, or 96 bits wide. 
     bit [8*12:1] stringvar = "Hello world\n";
```

Not sure if the old verilog supports it or not.

Comment: This answer is completely and utterly incorrect. Verilog does support character constants, and there is certainly nothing preventing a user from assigning hexadecimal values to registers!

Answer (score 9):

You can assign a string to a register type. Anyone who says otherwise is wrong. You might want to make your registers 0' based for it to work properly. I've done this in real FPGAs and it works.

Comment: To be clear. The verilog compiler will translate "A" to 8'h41, "AB" to 16'h4142, "ABC" to 24'h434241. Do not make it more complicated on yourselves by trying to think that the FPGA has to "support" this some how. All that happens is the compiler converts it from a nice human readable format into a number.

Comment: Yes string values are just constants. Although synthesis tool may or may not allow registers to have non-zero initialisation/reset values depending on the technology used. Recent X/A tools have no problem initialising shift registers from constants straight out of reset/programming.

Answer (score 7):

Define an array of bytes, then assign ASCII to each array element:

```
wire [7:0] foo [0:11];
assign foo[0]  = "H";
assign foo[1]  = "e";
assign foo[2]  = "l";
assign foo[3]  = "l";
assign foo[4]  = "o";
assign foo[5]  = " ";
assign foo[6]  = "W";
assign foo[7]  = "o";
assign foo[8]  = "r";
assign foo[9]  = "l";
assign foo[10] = "d";
assign foo[11] = "!";
```

You now have a constant with ASCII values in it that you can index into.

```
reg [7:0] data_out;
reg       data_out_valid;
reg [3:0] some_index;
:
// pushing data onto a bus
data_out       <= foo[some_index];
data_out_valid <= 1'd1;
some_index     <= some_index + 4'd1;
```

With appropriate index checking and control that should work.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
    reg [8*16:1] line1data = "Hello, World!   ";
```

Both in simulation and on a Spartan-3E FPGA

Comment: Just tested on ISE (Virtex-6), works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a demonstration of how strings work in a module:

```
module tb;

reg [8:1] char_value;

initial begin
    char_value = "A";
    $display("%h", char_value);
    if (char_value == 8'h41) begin
        $display("match");
    end else begin
        $display("no match");
    end
end

endmodule
```

Prints out:

```
41
match
```

The `string` data type was introduced into the SystemVerilog standard in 2005 (refer to IEEE 1800-2005 or 1800-2009).

Comment: I'm trying to assign the ASCII value to an 8-bit bus; I don't have `$display`.

Comment: For simulation, you can use string or $display. But if you are designing some code for FPGA. I think currently the synthesis tool doesn't support string type. From Xilinx they even doesn't support systemverilog now.

Answer (score 0):

```
output [8*14:1]string_value1;  
reg [8*14:1]string_value1;

always @ (posedge BIWEn)

if (BIWEn==1'b1 ||BIREn==1'b1)
    begin:START_STATE_WRITE
        psW=idleW;  //psW is Present State Write
        string_value1= "IDLE";
    end

![test bench] (c:\pictures)
```